# El programa no contiene un método 'Principal' estático adecuado para un punto de entrada

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una prueba para ver cómo imprime el valor del precio y obtengo el siguiente error

> Error CS5001 El programa no contiene un método 'Principal' estático adecuado para un punto de entrada

En mi clase Program.cs tengo el siguiente código

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;

namespace N_D
{
    class Program : Test
    {
        public  void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var price = 1450.00;

            precio = Convert.ToDecimal(price.ToString("N", new CultureInfo("es-VE")));

            Console.WriteLine("VALOR: " + precio);

            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Tengo otra clase llamada Test.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace N_D
{
    public class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            precio = 0;

        }

        public decimal precio;
    }
}
```

Cuando voy a compilar mi proyecto para luego ejecutarlo me da el error indicado arriba

> Error CS5001 El programa no contiene un método 'principal' estático adecuado para un punto de entrada N_D

Comment: El mismo error te lo dice, necesitas un static void Main(string[] args) y tu no lo tienes

Comment: @JorgeLuis en la clase Program.cs lo tiene pero sin el static debo agregarlo alli o  en la clase Test? Se que mi pregunta es muy tonta pero no logro verlo bn

Answer (score 1):

Tu Main debe ser Static.

```
class Program : Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Test test = new Test();

        var price = 1450.00;

        test.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(price, new CultureInfo("es-VE"));

        Console.WriteLine("VALOR: " + test.precio);

        var resultado = 0;

        Console.WriteLine(resultado);

        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

Comment: Al colocarlo así me daba error en las variables precio, se me olvidaba que tenia que crear un instancia para acceder a las propiedades de ellos

Comment: @TheRiddler no te deberia dar problema instanciar una clase. Pero mirando tu codigo te falta instanciar la clase Test

Comment: exacto era lo que faltaba y ya lo hice. Gracias por tus comentarios amigo

Comment: @TheRiddler Si la respuesta te ayudo, marcala como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Quedaria asi

CLASE **Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;

namespace N_D
{
    
        class Program : Test
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                var price = 1450.00;

                Test P = new Test();

                P.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(price.ToString("N", new CultureInfo("es-VE")));

                Console.WriteLine("VALOR: " + P.precio);

                Console.Read();

            }
        }
}
```

La CLASE Test.cs quedaria Igual

Answer (score 0):

[image: solucion1]

[image: solucion2]
[![solucion3][3]][3]

solucion 2
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaIbn.png
una ayuda rapidaaa

Comment: lasolucion es hacer de nuevo tus formulario o proyecto ya q se altero una opciones en el editos o el codigo esta mal o ha selecionado un proyecto q no lo detecta o falta un archivo .para que funcione

Comment: la otra solucion es que  en el proyecto no este la CLASE PROGRAM don alli esta el metodo MAINy llamada del formulario y tambien solucionar en formulario DESIGN la linea de codigo frmClave_load es borrarla esalinea de codigo y por ultimo te vas amenu PROYECTOdel id de C# y selecionas PROIEDADES DE PROYECTO y luego seleciona la ficha APLICACION Y luego la opcion OBJETO DE INICIO pones opcion program o no establecido y por utimo seleciona tambien la opcion  TIPO DE SALIDA: APLICACION DE WINDOWS y listo todo solucionado